# Issues hosting a server for Gmod

Tags: hosting, garrys-mod

I portforwarded Gmod but when I create a multiplayer game, nobody can join. This is how I portforwarded Gmod

```
Service Port:   27000-27015 (XX-XX or XX)
Internal Port:   (XX, Only valid for single Service Port or leave it blank)
IP Address:     192.168.x.x
Protocol:   all(all/tcp/udp)
Status:
```

Is there anything more I have to do? Or am I doing something wrong? (The server I want to host is not just for friends but for more "random" people Like the servers you can just find when browsing through servers)

Comment: You say you port forward, but on what? A router? Does your server firewall allow connections on these ports? When you say "nobody can join", does your server show up if they search for it?

Comment: @TZHX TP-Link(dont know exactly what comes after cause I'm not home right now, but I'll take a look when I'm home). Yes it does. No it doesn't.

Comment: @loko can your friends use `connect (your IP):27015` and connect to it?

Comment: Are those Xs in the IP address literally what's in the settings? The IP address should have actual numbers where the Xs are.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie No I got something like 192.168.1.1

Comment: @TZHX TL-WR841N

Comment: Are your friends searching for your external IP address? Is the server running (can you connect to it from your local network?)

Answer (score 1):

If your server status give a 192.168.X.X ip then you are hosting a lan server.

Try to open console and use `sv_lan 0` command (if you want to host over the internet) else `sv_lan 1` for lan server.

If you host an internet server you can look for your **external** ip [**here**](http://whatismyipaddress.com/). Thats the one your friends have to connect to.

Your port forwarding looks correct. You configured that the ports `27000-27015` are forwarded to the computer with the 192.168.x.x ip adress in your local network. However this 192.168.x.x has to be your local ip.

To see your local ip adress press the windows button or click on the start button (in your windows taskbar) and type `cmd` and press enter so a commandline will open. There you have to type `ipconfig /all` which gives you several network information. The important part is red marked (it's a german cmd here) the marked ip is the one you've to forward to.

[image: cmd with ipconfig command]

### Attention!

If you have a dynamic ip it is possible that your local ip change after you restart your computer which means that you would have to change the port forward to your current ip so better use a static local ip if your work with port forwarding.